# Fiddler stops StreamWriter timeout

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, fiddler

I'm stumped - looking for some help if possible....

I use Fiddler a lot to help me write code against remote APIs, have done for ages without any issues. Happy Days!

But, I have hit a problem I just cannot get my head around...

I am making a call to a remote API. When I make the call WITH fiddler running it works perfectly. When I make the very same call WITHOUT fiddler running, the call times out?

This is not just happening on my development machine. The client reported the problem first. And sure enough, when I asked him to install fiddler it works at his end as well!

I just cannot work out why making a call to this API fails only when Fiddler is not running and works when fiddler is running??

Can anyone suggest anything please?

This is my code:

```
public static SalesForceModel.ClipIdResponse getClipId(string instance_url, string access_token, string clipTitle)
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(instance_url + "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/vClip__c");
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"Type__c\":\"PowerPoint\"," +
                          "\"Title__c\":\"" + clipTitle + "\"}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SalesForceModel.ClipIdResponse>(result);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Typically* this behavior indicates that you've failed to properly close the stream returned by the `GetResponseStream()` function, as described in the *HTTPWebRequest* section of [this blog post](http://fiddler2.com/blog/blog/2013/02/28/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-).

However, your `using` statement *should* be properly disposing of the used `StreamReader` and that *should* be closing the underlying stream properly.

Is there any other use of HTTPWebRequest's `GetResponseStream()` function elsewhere in your app that might not be closing a stream? Is there a change in behavior if you explicitly call `httpResponse.Close()` after calling the `ReadToEnd()` method?